# Is there a name for a Wikipedia-like "W"?

Tags: typography

To be more precise: Is there a name for the type of font where the w's apex is shaped like a cross? Couldn't find it anywhere.

Note that the middle doesn't look like two successive v's, but rather like an x.
[image: here's said letter]

Comment: You may already know this, but just for completeness, let me note that the specific font originally used in the Wikipedia logo was [Hoefler Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoefler_Text), although it was later changed to [Linux Libertine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Libertine), with [a special variant glyph for the W.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47313/how-to-get-wikipedia-w-from-linux-libertine)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't find anything that refers to that in any other way than crossing centre strokes. Look [here](http://www.letterpress.dwolske.com/2010/04/24/799/) for reference.

However there is a pretty substantial glossary of type terms [here](https://www.fontshop.com/glossary) that calls the meeting point between letters a Vertex. The fact that this comprehensive list doesn't reference the crossing centre strokes as having a specific term suggests that there isn't one.

Looking into it further, it seems that fonts with those characteristics aren't necessarily identified by the cross in the strokes, but may actually be identified by the amount of upper terminals in the 'w' as [Identifont](http://identifont.com) does:

[image: Identifont screenshot]

Hope these help.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer! In the meantime the only other thing I could find is "crossed w" (http://typophile.com/node/100701) which seems far from being an established term though.

Comment: No worries, hope you find what you need!

Answer (score 2):

I thought it was just one of those antique-style letterpress types that Wikipedia chose to retain the association with 'timeless learning', 'classic', 'knowledge' and so on. But your question made me look it up and interestingly, I found something on a website called [Letterpress Daily](http://www.letterpress.dwolske.com/2010/12/28/do-you-copy/):
[image: 8 line Jenson Old Style]

Apparently this is called "[Jenson Old Style](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/woodentypefonts/jensen-old-style/)" and it's based on William Morris' "[Golden Type](http://www.identifont.com/find?name=william%20morris)" which was a version of types designed by [Nicolas Jenson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Jenson).

I don't know if this was/is what you were looking for, and Nibbers' answer is great, but I hope this info helps in addition to that.

Comment: And yes, on taking a second look I see it's not _exactly_  the same font but it might be a start.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia itself calls it a "crossed" W, part of the Linux Libertine font:

[image: Crossed W]

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Libertine#Usage